# Проблемы приведения типов List<T> зная тип обобщения как Type MyType

Tags: c#, list

Причина этого манёвра в том что моё значение "value" это Binding к некоторому полю/объекту из вне.
Есть проблема с приведением типов.
Type MyType;//Тип обобщения.

```
object value;//Есть вот такой универсальных хранитель объектов
```

Создаю List своего типа.

```
var proxyType = typeof(List<>);//Получаю тип листа
var genericClosedType = proxyType.MakeGenericType(MyType);//Оборачиваю сой тип Generic типом
value  = Activator.CreateInstance(genericClosedType);//Активирую/создаю объект
```

Первая попытка
Теперь пытаюсь добавить значение через dynamic

```
(value as dynamic).Add(MyType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[] { }))//я точно уверен что у моего типа GetConstructor(new Type[0])
```

Ошибка:
*Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.Collections.Generic.List<[мой тип]>.Add([мой тип])" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов*

Вторая попытка
Пытаюсь через Array зайти

```
var temp = Array.CreateInstance(MyType, Obj.Length + 1);
```

Всё прекрасно

```
for (int i = 0; i < Obj.Length; i++) { temp.SetValue((Obj.Value as dynamic)[i], i); }
temp.SetValue(createType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[] { }), Obj.Length);
```

Я даже перенёс значения
Но вот преобразовать в List уже не получается.

Где-то в конце попытка

```
value = temt.ToList();//Ошибка Array не содержит метод ToList
```

Теперь вопрос который меня мучает, как же добавить в мой лист значение?

1. Я не могу использовать `dynamic` вместо `object` так как используется
   Class : DependencyObject
2. Не могу типизировать свой класс к `Class<T>` так как мой объект это
   ClassContainer : Attribute

Но в одном я уверен точно данная конструкция очень хорошо работает при использовании Array. Может кто-нибудь знает как привести именно Array в List.

1. Интересный факт что object[].ToList() работает безотказно. Может кто
   нибудь знает как получить такой тип массива.
2. Или возможно кто-то знает как преобразовать в Generic типе.

Это малая часть кода. Мне нужно именно в List<[НЕИЗВЕСТНЫЙ ТИП ЗАРАНЕЕ]> добавить значение.

Данная задача решает вопрос автоматического создания некого интерфейса.
Есть набор атрибутов для разных типов данных (строки, числа, массивы)
Класс из свойств которого создаётся интерфейс и каждое свойство подписывается атрибутом.

Далее есть класс генерирующий интерфейс.
Он берёт свойства объекта и биндит их к уже готовым **UserControl**.

Это работает уже давно. Но постепенно я добрался к **List**
С массивами проблем нет.
И вот теперь не могу правильно подобрать один единственный метод. Add.

На данный момент появилась идея возможно просто костыль. Создать ещё один атрибут у свойства, но типизированный. И его передавать основному атрибуту через ссылку.

Comment: `GetConstructor(...).Invoke(...)` возвращает `object`, а не `MyType`.

Comment: Можете вызвать конструктор `new List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`, передав ему массив. И зачем вам вообще список? Количество элементов неизвестно? Но вообще вы странного хотите.

Comment: Если вы прочитаете начало, то увидите что это Binding свойство. Использовать (IEnumerable<T>) не получится я не знаю заранее <T>

Comment: что такое `MyType` и откуда оно берется?

Comment: /// <summary>Имя сайта</summary>
        [StringEdit("Имя сайта", Position = (int)PositionE.NameSite, PropertyUpdate = new string[] { nameof(TextShow) })]
        [Group((int)GroupID.Сайт, Hint = "", Visible = nameof(IsShow))]
        public string NameSite { get; set; }

Comment: не вставляйте код в комменты, вставляйте в сам пост, его можно редактировать

Comment: Вот такой пример. И тут Attribute используется как универсальный конструктор визуального интерфейса.

Comment: В таких случаях проще всего создать generic - метод, где и описать всю необходимую логику и уже сам метод вызывать через рефлексию (разумеется с ускорением), чем писать такие заклинания

Comment: Не могу я использовать Generic методы. Вы читали? Это Attribute

Comment: можете конечно. Если у вас затык  с детальной кодогенераций (или просто лень), то обычный код в generic методе решит ваши проблемы

Comment: [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)] в правильном ли направлении я копаю?

Comment: проблема вашего кода - невозможно понять какую задачу решаете. Какие то dynamic. Вы создали List<T> через рефлексию и вам нужно добавлять в него элементы? Ну так достаньте через ту же рефлексию списковый метод Add и вызывайте его. Пока не захочется ускорить

Comment: Интересно то что абсолютно все игнорируют что у меня атрибут. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294216/why-does-c-sharp-forbid-generic-attribute-types вот ссылка на зарубежный аналог и там объясняют что нельзя generic создать из атрибута.

Comment: Потому что это не имеет значения. Если не получается кодогенерация, то вместо попытки самому нагенерить код создаете обычный метод (и за вас все сгенерит рантайм), который и вызываете через рефлексию. А внутри этого метода даже dynamic работать будет (я добавил в пример), потому что там можно привести к настоящему типу, а не работать с `object`

Comment: Блин это очень круто. Я честно как баран упёрся в class<T> и совершенно забыл про методы. Однако я и не знал что так можно свои методы создавать. Огромно спасибо! Три дня мучался:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу на вопрос "Мне нужно именно в List<[НЕИЗВЕСТНЫЙ ТИП ЗАРАНЕЕ]> добавить значение."

MyType не хочет работать через dynamic, потому что по факту это `object` (потому что создан рефлексей) и, даже найдя нужную перегрузку `Add`, среда выполнения не может скормить ему `object`.

Поэтому вы можете просто получить списковый метод `Add`и вызывать его через рефлексию.
(Потом уже ускорить его через кодогенерацию)

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myType = typeof(Foo);

        //список
        var proxyType = typeof(List<>); //Получаю тип листа
        var genericClosedType = proxyType.MakeGenericType(myType); //Оборачиваю сой тип Generic типом
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(genericClosedType); //Активирую/создаю объект

        //инстанцируем item
        var item = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

        // напрямую
        var addMethod= list.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(IList.Add), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        addMethod.Invoke(list, new[] { item });
        
        //ну и всегда можно сделать отдельный generic - метод. 
        //Для такого простого случая нет нужды, но для примера будет.
        var genMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(AddToList), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(myType);
        var addAction = (Action<object, object>)genMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object, object>));

        addAction(list, item);

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }


    public static void AddToList<T>(object list, object item)
    {
        ((IList<T>)list).Add((T)item);
        //и тут уже будет работать dynamic, но зачем???
        //(list as dynamic).Add((T)item);
    }

    private class Foo
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: @SovaSasha Также можно использовать и абстрактный класс с абстрактным методом(ами) `abstract void FuncName(object ...)` и конкретный generic-класс наследник. Инстанцировать этот конкретный класс с помощью рефлексии, привести к базовому классу и пользоваться. Туда и список можно передать в конструктор, чтобы постоянно в методы не передавать. И что-либо хранить в полях класса. И несколько методов. (хотя поверх вот таких generic-методов тоже можно класс-враппер сделать). В общем, кому что нравится.